# Swift Call an override method by subclass from superclass

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two classes in swift. I have an action method that I want to override in many subclasses that will do a different action. I wanted this to sort of function like an abstract class in Java, where I could pass a bunch of different subclasses of a certain class, but they would be referred to from the superclass so that one method could be called for all of them even though they are different subclasses with different overridden versions of that one method. Here is what I mean.

```
class1: SKSpriteNode{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)     
    }

    func action(){ print("this should never be called") }
}

class2: class1 {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)   
    }

    override func action() {
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    }
}
```

I would want to do something like this. A node with name someName would be defined as a class2 in the SKScene editor.

```
class GameScene...

let node = self.childNode(withName: "someName") as? class1
noe.action()
```

However, I never get the output I want. I always get the call of class1 even when I want it to be overridden as a class2 and turn on gravity for that node. I would want to call the action method for many subclasses of class1 no matter the subclass, so just changing the class1 method to do what I want will not work.

Thank you

EDIT: Here are my actual classes:
So I have some classes that are nodes that will be triggered when the user passes the trigger node. It has a stored value for the name of the target node that is then retrieved from the main SKScene, its parent. Then I want to have a specific TargetNode, DropNode that will make it fall from the sky, but I want to be able to trigger any subclass of TargetNode by calling the TriggerAction method, but it never seems to perform the code of the subclass, the DropNode, but instead always does nothing/ whatever code I put in the action method of the TargetNode class. It never overrides the method.

```
//SUPERCLASS:
import Foundation

class SKTargetNode: SKGlowNode {



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

           super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    func action(){
         print("i don't want this to be called")
    }

}

//SUBCLASS:
import Foundation

class SKDropNode: SKTargetNode {



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

           super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }


    override func action() {
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    }
}

//Just a class that triggers any TargetNode
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class SKTriggerNode: SKSpriteNode {



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

           super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }


    func triggerAction(_ scene: GameScene){
        let nodeName = self.userData?.value(forKey: "TargetNode") as? String ?? ""
        let node = scene.childNode(withName: "//\(nodeName)") as? SKTargetNode
        node?.action()

    }

}
```

Comment: you say "A node with name someName would be defined as a class2" and then your code says "self.childNode(withName: "someName") as? class1" is it a class1 or class2

Comment: It is defined as a class2 but I am referencing it by its superclass, a class1, so that I can call the action method for all subclasses

Comment: you want to be doing protocol oriented programming

Comment: Polymorphism does work in Swift, I use it all the time. Can you provide some minimal code that reproduces the problem, so we can check it?

Comment: Exactly you can use polymorphism, but I think with protocols you can do what you are trying to, could you give us a better example?

Comment: @Yonat Here, I updated it with my actual code. It all starts with the triggeredAction method being called from another class. The node is always retrieved successfully

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint at the last line of `triggerAction()` and then in the debugger console  enter `p node`?